# Round numbers with flask.jsonify

Tags: python, json, namedtuple

Here is an array with Prediction `namedtuple`s that I'm returning with `flask.jsonify`.

```
y = current_app.extensions['classifier'].classify(url=maybe_image_url)
return jsonify(y=y)
```

What would be the best way to round the probability percentages to two decimals?

```
[Prediction(rank=1, category='dog', probability=0.99999475479125977), Prediction(rank=2, category='sheep', probability=5.2518985285132658e-06), Prediction(rank=3, category='cat', probability=1.3360376693860587e-10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`namedtuple`s are immutable (because they're tuples, and that's pretty much tuple's thing) so you can't do an assignment, but they have a nice method called `_replace` for making a copy with the appropriate value changed.

```
y = [p._replace(probability=round(p.probability, 2)) for p in y]
```

Comment: Right, your solution works with the named touple in question.